# Outlook REST API Flagging Message losing start date

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail, outlook-graph-api

I'm building an Outlook Add-In and using the Outlook REST API 2.0. When updating a mail message to flag the message for follow-up, the update is accepted and in the Outlook Web client it briefly shows the start and due dates, but within a few seconds the start date goes away. When looking at the message through the API, the start date is completely removed, even though it was successfully added.

The API is PATCH Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/me/messages/' + messageId ...

EDIT: I confirmed that this same behavior is exhibited in the Graph API as well.

As soon as the API is called, the UI on the message is updated:

[image]

Shortly after that (sometimes within a second, sometimes a little longer), the UI changes to:

[image]

And once the UI updates, if you query the API for the message and look at the Flag property, the StartDateTime object is completely gone.

Has anyone seen this or know why it might be happening?

Comment: We can reproduce the same issue when using a Graph API call changing the FlagStatus. This seems to be a REST API issue, unrelated to add-ins - we have updated tags appropriately so you can get better resolution for this.

Comment: Thank you ... do you know if someone from the REST API team actively monitors for the outlook-restapi tag or is there a better way to engage them?

Answer (score 1):

Checked it on Graph with the following payload for PATCH-Message call and it seems to be working fine.

{"flag":{"dueDateTime":{"dateTime":"2020-08-20T00:00:00.0000000","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"},"flagStatus":"flagged","startDateTime":{"dateTime":"2020-08-14T00:00:00.0000000","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"}}}

I suspect that there is another application/outlook add-in that's removing this flag. Can you check once?

Comment: OK, that's very strange. I tested it again yesterday before I mentioned this again on Twitter and it was still doing it. But now I tried it this morning and it isn't. I'll monitor for a bit to see if I see it happen again.